# If $|z|<1$ , show that $\left|\frac{1}{2}\arg (\frac{1+z}{1-z}) \right| < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $|z|<1$ , show that $\left|\frac{1}{2}\arg (\frac{1+z}{1-z}) \right| < \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: I tried too enough

Comment: I think the answer should be pi/4. let w = 1+z/1-z. We know that Re w > 0 in |z|<1. Then |arg w|< pi/2. therefore |1/2 arg w |< 1/2 * pi/2 = pi/4. Correct me if i am wrong.Thanks

Comment: I think you are true but what about the other values of the (arg ) we treat with Principle value   but arg z = $theta$+2k(pi) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1+x+iy}{1-x-iy}=\frac{(1+x+iy)(1-x+iy)}{(1-x)^2+y^2}=\frac{1-y^2-x^2+2y i}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$$

From the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) of  atan2, here  we need $1-y^2-x^2>0$

Comment: I think the answer should be pi/4. let w = 1+z/1-z. We know that Re w > 0 in |z|<1. Then |arg w|< pi/2. therefore |1/2 arg w |< 1/2 * pi/2 = pi/4. Correct me if i am wrong.Thanks

Comment: @measure2012, agreed. Thanks for your observation

Comment: Thanks for checking for my answer.

Comment: I agree with measure2012 because I try it

Comment: what about the other values of the (arg ) we treat with Principle value   but arg z = $theta$+2k(pi) ??

Comment: @HamadaAl, I believe here the OP meant has meant the Principal Value only